# How to keep PHP session persistent, with custom session ID?

Tags: php, session

Very simple experiment.  I have an `index.php` which contains:

```
if ( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) {
    session_id( random_string() );
    session_start();
}

echo session_id();
```

`random_string()` simply returns a random 20 char A-Z,a-z,0-9 string.

On reloading this page it will ALWAYS generate a new session ID since there isn't a call to `session_start()` before that `if` statement, and the (resuming) `$_SESSION` super global doesn't exist.

However, if I put a call to `session_start()` at the top of the script I've lost my chance to specify a custom session ID, since setting a custom ID has to happen **before** the call to `session_start()`.

I just can't figure this out.  Chicken/egg problem.  So, how do I successfully implement a custom session ID, which will keep the super global alive between page loads?

Comment: PHP sessions are notoriously unreliable. It is better to use a database for sessions.

Comment: So, you want to stay with the same session id until the browser is closed or per user?

Answer (score 0):

You can have your own customized session id throughout pages with the help of file system and database. I've written the following code to keep track of same session id through all the pages using file system method:

```
if(filesize('session_track.txt') === 0) {
    file_put_contents('session_track.txt', random_string());
}

$session_id = file_get_contents('session_track.txt');
session_id($session_id);
session_start();

// Here is the conditional statement, in case you need to regenerate your custom session id again
$regenerate_custom_session_id = false; // if need, set it to true.

// This code depends on your requirements. I just mentioned this conditional statement for your understanding to make it logically work
if($regenerate_custom_session_id === true) {
    file_put_contents('session_track.txt', '');
}
```

I'm not sure how efficient this code is. I've just shared my idea to make it work.